# If $A$ has the same cardinality as $B$, then $A \setminus B$ has the same cardinality as $B \setminus A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ has the same cardinality as $B$, then $A \setminus (A \cap B)$ has the same cardinality as $B \setminus (A \cap B)$.

If the sets are finite, then this is easy to see. But how to prove this in general?

I'm thinking along the following lines. Define $C = A \cap B$, $D = A \setminus C$, $E = B \setminus C$. So $B = C \cup D$ and $B = C \cup E$.
Suppose $f$ is the bijection from $A$ to $B$. Write
$$
B = (C \cap f(C)) \cap (C \cap f(E)) \cap (E \cap f(C)) \cap (E \cap f(E)). 
$$
I think I need to redefine the map based on this decomposition. But I don't see how. And I'm not sure if this is fruitful.

Comment: It is not true in general. Take pairwise distinct $a,b,c\notin\mathbb{N}$ (e.g., $a=\{1\}$, $b=\{2\}$ and $c=\{3\}$ and consider $A=\{a\}\cup\mathbb{N}$, $B=\{b,c\}\cup\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Let $E$ be the set of even positive integers and $\Bbb Z^+$ the set of positive integers. These sets have the same cardinality, but $E\setminus\Bbb Z^+=\varnothing$, while $\Bbb Z^+\setminus E$ is the infinite set of odd positive integers.

Comment: It holds for finite sets as we have a cancellation law for finite cardinals: $|A| = |A \setminus (A \cap B)| + |A \cap B| = |B| = |B \setminus (A \cap B)|$ and we cancel $|A \cap B| \in \Bbb N$ from both sides to get $|A \setminus (A \cap B)| = |B \setminus (A \cap B)|$ No such luck in infinite sets: $1 + |\Bbb N| = |\Bbb N| + |\Bbb N|$ but we cannot cancel out $|\Bbb N|$ from both sides, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prove it in general, take $A=\Bbb Q$, $B=\Bbb N$. Both are countable, but $A\setminus B$ is infinite, $B \setminus A$ is empty.